# How to transfer multiple factors into one row?

Tags: r, row, aggregate, factors

I have a dataframe with 8 variables:

[image]

For the variable `Labor Category`, we have 5 factors: Holiday Worked, Regular, Overtime, Training, Other Worked.

The question is: Can I find a way to aggregate rows with same values except `Labor Category` and sum up the `Sum_FTE`variable？

i.e. Can we reduce the number of rows while add more columns:

"Labor.CategoryHoliday.Worked","Labor.CategoryOther.Worked","Labor.CategoryOvertime","Labor.CategoryRegular","Labor.CategoryTraining" and use 0 or 1 to indicate the status of each factor. And then sum up the Total FTE from rows with same values except Labor Category.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do one of group by operations.  Using `dplyr`, we specify the column names in the `group_by` as grouping variables and then get the `sum` of "Sum_FTE" with `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots= names(df1)[c(1:2,4:5)]) %>%
    summarise(TotalFTE= sum(Sum_FTE))
```

---

For the second part of the question, we can use `dcast` (it would have been better to show the dataset with `dput` instead of image file)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, N := 1:.N, (Labor.Category)]
dcast(df1, Med.Center+Charged.Job+Month+Pay.Period.End ~N, 
          value.var="Labor.Category, length)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. But for the second part, I created more than 20,000 new variables, which indicates it's incorrect.

Comment: @BeichenLin  The second part I also had doubts, as I couldn't test it without a proper example.  You posted an image, from that it is difficult to create a working example.  Can you update your post with `dput` output of the example i.. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata,10)))` and the expected output based on that example.